# Do dragonskin cloths provide wearer with protection against spells?

Tags: harry-potter

We know that dragons are spell-resistant (from GoF).

Is there any **canon** support for the fact that dragonskin cloths provide wearer with protection against spells?

Comment: NOTE: Wikia is NOT canon, [I know what Wikia has to say](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon-skin_coat) on the topic but it has no canon cites. Canon is book texts, JKR interviews or statements on web sites whose content originates directly from JKR

Comment: I think the source of wikia for this statement is video games (chiwh I know are not canon), but I cannot prove it.

Comment: @Kalissar - my question didn't original from Wikia. I just posted the comment to pre-empt useless Wikia-quoting answer that I was sure to see pop up immediately.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can’t find any canon sources that confirm that dragon-skin cloths provide protection against **spells** specifically, but I do have a few quotes that might be of interest.

In *Goblet of Fire*, chapter 18, when Hagrid has the students handling Blast-Ended Skrewts:

> “Yeh might want ter put on yer dragon-hide gloves, jus’ as an extra precaution, like.”

Then in *Order of the Phoenix*, chapter 19, we have them again:

> The skies and the ceiling of the Great Hall turned a pale, pearly grey, the mountains around Hogwarts were snowcapped, and the temperature in the castle dropped so low that many students wore their thick protective dragon skin gloves in the corridors between lessons.

These two quotes tell us is that the skin protects against Skrewts and cold, but that probably isn’t beyond a particularly well-made pair of Muggle gloves.

The entry on dragons in *Fantastic Beasts* has a little more-information:

> Dragon hide, blood, heart, liver, and horn all have highly magical properties

Although we already knew this instinctively, it’s nice to have a canon reference. Reading between the lines, the obvious “highly magical properties” for the dragon hide are that it protects the wearer against some spells (although probably not to the same degree as a dragon’s protection).

Later on, it’s confirmed that dragon skin is used for protection (although again, the scope of the protection isn’t defined).

> The Swedish Short-Snout is an attractive silvery-blue dragon whose skin is sought after for the manufacture of protective gloves and shields.

In the same book, we also have the following line:

> Graphorn hide is even tougher than a dragon’s and repels most spells.

I think that could be seen as canonical precedent for animal hide protecting against spells, even if dragons aren’t specifically mentioned by name.

**Edited to add:**

As [balanced mama](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/10926/balanced-mama) correctly points out in the comments, they’re not just used in Care of Magical Creatures; they also come up in Herbology. This is still showing protective purposes, not magic specifically, but worth noting anyway.

In *Goblet of Fire*, chapter 13, as the class are bottling Bubotuber pus, Professor Sprout tells them to don their dragon-hide gloves:

> “You will collect the pus, I say, in these bottles. Wear your dragon-hide gloves; it can do funny things to the skin when undiluted, bubotuber pus.”

It also reminded me that they’re mentioned on the list of items for first-years to bring.
In chapter 5 of *Philosopher's Stone*:

> First-year students will require: […] One pair of protective gloves (dragon hide or similar)

Comment: Amazing compilation.

Comment: Nice answer!!  One thing to add though, I believe they were required in herbology, and definitely worn by Prof Sprout - again it is only an example of protective properties and likely were simply worn to ward off contact with toxic substances and scrapes from thorns and the like, but Dragon hide was the specific thing that was required so they certainly provide protection above and beyond what muggle gardening gloves provide.

Comment: @balancedmama: ooh, good catch. There are a few bits where they’re specifically mentioned, so I’ll edit them in.